# Custom changes (Bold) to text inside environment

Tags: environments, bold, verse

I am using an custom environment that typesets a verse as follows:

```
\newenvironment{Verse}[1][]
 {\center#1\varwidth{\linewidth}}
  {\endvarwidth\endcenter}
```

Using this I can generate a verse that is centered on a page like this.

```
\begin{Verse}
Twinkle Twinkle little star\\
How I wonder what you are
\end{Verse}
```

[image]

I want to be able to bold a portion of the verse. Say I want to bold the phrase 'what you are' in the above example. I tried by enclosing 'what you are' within a `textbf`, but it doesn't work.

```
\begin{Verse}
Twinkle Twinkle little star\\
How I wonder \textbf{what you are}
\end{Verse}
```

I also tried `{\bfseries what you are}` and that doesn't work either.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Does not work (either)` is no precise statement. Please post a compilable version of your document

Comment: Sorry, but if I add a standard preamble to your code snippet and change `what you are` into `\textbf{what you are}` I get no issue. Please, make a minimal example, starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`, that shows the error.

Comment: Presumably you had a warning in the log that there is no bold version of the font that you are using, but as you did not show the warning, nor provide usable input, nor say what font you are using,  it is hard to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Carlisle's guess was spot on. There was no bold version of the font on my machine. Thanks to all that responded in the comments.